# Position fixed error only in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox

I'm building a new website, but i'm having issues with a simpel task - creating a sticky nav.

It works perfectly in Safari and Chrome, also on mobile browsers, but not in firefox.

Do anyone have some idéas on what might be wrong?

PS. Try the website in Safari first. The Nav appears when you scroll abit down.

**http://shakeinteractive.no/shkpress/**

Comment: The menu is sticking on the top of your `#nav_scroll`. http://i.imgur.com/sGUgSQu.gif

Comment: What do you mean?
I wand the #nav_scroll to by fixed / sticky.

All the emelents inside the nag is position with absolute or relative..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<html>` is styled with a transform.  That means that all `position: fixed` in there is now fixed to that element's box, not to the viewport.  So when the `<html>` scrolls, the `#nav_scroll` also scrolls.

The relevant CSS rule looks like this:

```
html, html a {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Notice that it's not using `-webkit-translate3d` and at this point browsers based on WebKit/Blink are the only ones that don't support unprefixed CSS transforms. So that rule is not setting a transform on `<html>` in Chrome or Safari, which is why your page works there.